# Unknown command message while using route add in mininet

Tags: routes, router, hosts, mininet

I am trying to connect two hosts with a router. I am trying the "route add" command on the mininet platform for which I am getting an error:

> Unknown command

I tried adding the hosts to the router which was successful but the hosts are unable to communicate with each other.

The simple topo of two hosts connected to a router is:

```
h1----->r1<------h2
```

Below is the command which I am using for routing the host:

```
route add -host 8.8.8.1 netmask 8.8.8.0/24 gateway 8.8.8.10
```

Can someone help me resolve the problem so that the hosts can ping each other.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you writing the command?

Comment: on the mininet emulator

Answer (score 1):

The command is unknown to Mininet. But you can run it inside a Mininet node, so you should specify a node name before the command. example:

```
h1 route add -host 8.8.8.1 netmask 8.8.8.0/24 gateway 8.8.8.10
```